# Securing my Azure Web App with HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, azure-web-app-service

Say, for example, I have an Azure web app named MyApp and is hosted on Azure as MyApp.azurewebsites.net. It's my understanding that there is nothing I need to do to secure the URL with SSL, as it's done, by default, with a single certificate. So I can already have my users access the app via https://MyApp.azurewebsites.net, and it will be secure right out of the box.

However, say I have another URL named www.MyApp.com that I want to point (redirect) to https://MyApp.azurewebsite.net. Do I have to secure www.MyApp.com with a certificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I have to secure www.MyApp.com with a certificate?

Yes, we could get more detail info from the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate) .

> To secure your custom domain name with HTTPS, you bind a custom SSL certificate to that custom domain in Azure.

Before binding a custom certificate, we need to do the following:

> **Configure the custom domain** - App Service only allows adding a certificate for a domain name that's already configured in your app. For instructions, see [Map a custom domain name to an Azure app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name).
>
> **Scale up to Basic tier or higher** App Service plans in lower pricing tiers don't support custom SSL certificates. For instructions, see [Scale up an app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-scale).
>
> **Get an SSL certificate** - If you do not already have one, you need to get one from a trusted certificate authority (CA).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use a custom host name, then you will need to have a certificate for it. There is really no way around this, based on how SSL works.